# Why non-ui thread can not modify view properties?

Tags: android, multithreading, uiview, frameworks

In android, if I want to modify some view's properties in non-ui thread(e. g. setText for TextView), I have to write codes like these:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     textView.setText("Hello world");
 });
```

And in c#,i have to use a delegate,which is more complicated.

So why they(framework) don't help us to do these thing in inner code like the following?

```
void setText(string text){
    if(isInMainThread()){
       //direct set text
    }else{
       post(new Runnable(){
         setText(text);
       });
    }
}
```

Is there any reason similiar to java thread stop method deprecated because the flow need to be controled by coder?

Thanks in advance, and forgive my poor english.

Comment: All the UI drawing related work is done in 1 thread hence and code that alters the UI should be pushed to this thread otherwise there will be concurrency issues

Comment: I agree. But why framework do not help us to do these exra thing, they can detect if not in main thread then record it and do these thing in main thread later.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Because of Android's single-threaded architecture, UI toolkit is not thread-safe.

Here you can find the full answer from Android's official documentation [Android - Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> When an application component starts and the application does not have any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux process for the application with a single thread of execution. By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and thread (called the "main" thread).

Additionally:

> The Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> 1. Do not block the UI thread
> 2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

Comment: the thread creator understands why android is single threaded, what he wants to know is why methods like `TextView.setText` take care of checking if that particular method is being executed on the UI thread, if not run the code in the UI thread instead. Like the code snippet he posted in his question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree, creators could do that, but probably it came from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) design of Android architecture.

**SOLID** is an acronym, which stands for 5 basic principles of object-oriented programming and design. In my opinion if view'd checked thread on which method was called, it would violate **Single-responsibility** principle - should view be responsible for checking which thread was used? IMHO it shouldn't. I think creators of Android would agree with me ;)

As far as I know in current architecture, when you change text by `setText` method, view sends notification that its state has changed and it's OS responsibility to redraw it, but to be honest I still don't know details about how it is exactly handled.

Moreover with this approach, Android creators tried to encourage application developers to think what operations are called on which thread - e.g. big computation task shouldn't be part of UI animation.